# The server responded with a status of 500 (Server Error)

Tags: html, error-handling, href

I have designed a website using wix.com

I download a sample CSV templates that wix have provided, entered the data and imported the products to my wix store. Under the description column I entered the HTML `<a href="URL">TEXT< /a>`.

For the URL I entered my affiliate link.

For the TEXT I entered “Shop Now”

I was able to import nearly 100 products, no issues. The next day I tried to import products by clicking on "add to catalog" on Wix, an error message appeared on the wix store saying:

> This page has stopped responding

When I clicked on Developer Tools on Google there was an error message:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Server Error)
>
> 512 log entires are not shown

I am only unable to import products if I enter `<a href=` in the description column (if I just typed a word or a url I can import products to my Wix store).

I do not understand why I was able to import products on day and when I tried to import products the next day using the same method I keep getting this error message.

I am not a developer. I have a very limited knowledge about computers. I have spoken to the Wix customer service about this but still no luck with an answer.

Comment: A 500 error is a "general server fault" and it can mean anything. For web apps you have developed yourself, we would normally advise checking your server logs, to see what 500 means in any given case. However, since you are using a consumer web application, only Wix really knows what this means. Your best bet it probably to pursue an enquiry with their tech support staff.

Comment: Tip: if you wish to format a small piece of code (as per the HTML in your message), wrap it with "backticks" (the oblique apostrophe, usually above the Tab key). It `looks like this` and will ensure that HTML is shown correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: Hi, I received a message from Wix support team. They have resolve the issue. Thank you kindly for your information. I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score -1):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I received a message from Wix support team. They have resolve the issue.